# Why did the Galactic Senate grant emergency powers to Chanceller Palpatine but would not vote to create a Republic army?

Tags: star-wars

Isn't it almost the same thing? Didn't they know Palpatine's leanings on the military bill and that he would likely form an army. And why didn't the same senators feel dissapointed when Palpatine announced that an army would be created if many of them would not vote for the same? Did they regret granting him powers for this reason?

Did they simply not want to take responsibilty for creating an army and justifying it to their populations?

Comment: Because armies are expensive?

Answer (score 3):

The war was more then just creating an army. other decisions would have to been made and in such a large democracy the bureaucracy would slow them down to much to be effective in a war.

Also they believed that Palpatine himself was heavily against a war and that he would relinquish these powers and disband the army when the time came.